# Pandas to calculate date differences in dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Two columns in a csv file as below. I want to check the date intervals of each,

i.e.

'2013-11-01' - '2013-10-08',

'2013-12-02' - '2013-11-01' etc.

[image]

After,

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')
df_date = df["Date"]
```

I tried:

```
print (df["Date"].shift(-1) - df["Date"]).astype('timedelta64[d]')
```

and

```
print df['Date'].shift() - df['Date']
```

both of them returned:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

What went wrong, and how can I correct it? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried converting the columns to datetime before taking the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is column `Date` is filled string repr of datetimes, so first is necessary converting - e.g. by `parse_dates` parameter or [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then call [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', parse_dates=['Date'])

print (df["Date"].diff(-1))
```

Another solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
print (df["Date"].diff(-1))
```

Comment: hope you are very well. thank you for the lightening speed solution, and sharing of knowledge!